# UNABLE TO CREATE A NEW SPRING STARTER PROJECT

Tags: spring

I'm not able to create a spring starter project in sts tool(spring tool suite).

While trying to create a new spring starter project then I have received the "Artifact transfer exception" error.
And also I have attached the screen shot for the same.

Can you help on this.

Comment: you can look into this [transferException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425941/m2eclipse-issues-artifacttransferexception-but-pom-xml-compiles-installs-fro)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [m2eclipse issues ArtifactTransferException - But pom.xml compiles / installs from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425941/m2eclipse-issues-artifacttransferexception-but-pom-xml-compiles-installs-fro)

Answer (score 0):

Try spring initializer  (https://start.spring.io/), just substitute your values, then click generate, unarchive project and open, and all must works.

Comment: While that is one way to create a Spring Project, this doesn't help solve the issue in question.

Answer (score 0):

Acoording to the link that Stephen C said in his comment: 
[m2eclipse issues ArtifactTransferException - But pom.xml compiles / installs from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425941/m2eclipse-issues-artifacttransferexception-but-pom-xml-compiles-installs-fro)

1. Open folder by running this text (without Quotes) in Search Explorer of Window “%USERPROFILE%.m2″.
2. After running above command, “m2″ folder of maven will open. Now search for file (without Quotes) “*.lastUpdated”.
3. In this step, delete all the files found by running Step 2.
4. Now go to Eclipse project and select “Maven | Update Dependency” or “Maven | Update Project”.